# SSH: Set umask before command execution

Tags: bash, ssh, umask

I am writing a  script which will SSH into a remote server and execute some commands. The problem I am facing is that the commands are altering file permissions on the remote server which is unintended.

What I normally do, is to `ssh` to the server (thus opening a login shell) and execute the command manually with `umask` value set to `0007` (`umask 0007` is included in `.bash_profile` of the remote server, and is thus the default value for the login shell).

Assume the command is called `some-command`. It looks to me as if `ssh` executes all commands with a default `umask` value of `0022` if the `<command>` option is supplied.

```
$ ssh user@ip.address "umask && some-command"
0022
```

I was thinking of prepending the command with `umask 0007` as below, which seems to work:

```
$ ssh user@ip.address "umask 0007 && umask && some-command"
0007
```

But is there a clean way to do this? Perhaps by specifying an option with `ssh`?

Comment: See `man 8 pam_umask`.

Comment: or just add it to ~/.ssh/rc

Comment: Unfortunately adding to `~/.ssh/rc` doesn't change the umask on the remote server. `umask` still returns `0022`.